# Mysql : How insert columns with values to preexisting table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have table with 3 columns(id, username, password) I wanted to copy these 3 columns to different tables, I copied but deleted(password) one of the columns in the new tables mistakenly. Now I want to copy the column from old table to the new table. But I dont know how to do it . Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this if your old table and different table share the same column names:

```
UPDATE different_table DT
INNER JOIN old_table OT ON DT.id = OT.id AND DT.username = OT.username
SET DT.password = OT.password.
```

Comment: Explain **not working**. May be you need to provide the exact table structures of these two tables.

Comment: 0 rows affected means there's nothing to update in the target table. May be passwords are same across these tables.

Comment: firstly there was no column called password(so no value) in the second table so I created it, and then executed your code. I feel your code should work fine. But in my case it's not working I don't know why

Comment: Then why don't you share the exact table structures of these two tables? I think it would be helpful.